# React rendering string after function with logic/looping

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Hi I want to render a string with looping logic behind it so I decided to put a function that will return the string

```
function Leasing(){
  let {idLeasingExact} = useParams()

  const checkParam = () =>{
    //return(idLeasingExact)
    dropdownItems.map((item,index) => {
        if(idLeasingExact == item.path){
          console.log(idLeasingExact)
          console.log(item.path)
          console.log(item.title)
          return(
          item.title
        )
      }
    })
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <h1>
        {idLeasingExact ? checkParam() : "Leasing"
        }
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Leasing;
```

here is the dropdown item

```
export const dropdownItems = [
  {
    title:'SMF',
    path:'1',
    cName:'dropdown-link'
  },
  {
    title:'BFI',
    path:'2',
    cName:'dropdown-link'

  },
  {
    title:'ADIRA',
    path:'3',
    cName:'dropdown-link'

  }
]
```

I use param and that param will be used in function checkParam to return the result

the checkParam() should return the title(SMF BFI ADIRA) as the result

for example, if it's leasing/1
it should've return the title of SMF

or if it's leasing/2
it should've returned the title of BFI
but it returns null,
although the console log on the browser shows the right item.title just like the example

help appreciated I'm stuck here thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you're not wanting to actually do a `map`. You gotta `find` the item on `dropdownItems` with `path` equals to `idLeasingExact`. Try changing your `checkParam()` function to something like this:

```
const checkParam = () => {
    const item = dropdownItems.find(x => x.path == idLeasingExact);
    if (item) return item.title;
    else {
        // do whatever you want if path is not found, for example:
        return 'No title found.'
    }
}
```

*What your code is doing, is some sort of a conditional mapping and the function `checkParam()` is not actually returning something if you take a close look (the function inside the map does return the `.title`, not the `checkParam()`!)*

Comment: thanks this is the answer , and i can do looping to to return it with for (var ....
But why cant i use .map ?

Comment: @JzxNaga `Array.prototype.map` returns an array, not any specific element from the array, and then on top of that, you weren't even returning the mapped array back to your JSX return.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't answer this before. `map` is to kind of `mutate` the content of the array (you may find a better explanation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). What you're trying to do is to `find` an element of the array and then return and specific attribute of it so there is no sense on using map here (`find` docs can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

map() returns a list. checkParam() is not returning that list. Just add return to the function-

```
    const checkParam = () =>{
    return dropdownItems.map((item,index) => {
        if(idLeasingExact == item.path){
          return(
          item.title
        )
      }
    })
  }
```

Also, you can add your JSX logic in checkParam itself like this-

```
    const checkParam = () => {
    return dropdownItems.map((item, index) => {
      if (idLeasingExact == item.path) {
        return <h1>{item.title}</h1>
      } else {
        return <h2>{"Leasing"}</h2>
      }
    })
  }

  return <div>{checkParam()}</div>
```

This will give you more control based on idLeasingExact value (e.g. conditional styling)